# What exactly will the architecture for a Rails app and mobile app look like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, parse-platform

So I am creating both a Rails app and they are getting a mobile app created for their project.

I would prefer to use Heroku and that whole tool chain because I love it. It is simple, has lots of caching add-ons, is cheap/free on the low-end and can scale up easily.

However, they want a mobile client that can also do the same thing the Rails app can do.

It obviously doesn't make sense running two different databases (one on Heroku and the other on Parse - which is what they want to use).

So how do I setup both apps to use the same DB?

Do I just create a public-facing API from the Rails app and have the mobile client ping those endpoints?

Do I use Parse for the mobile stuff, and write the Rails app to use the Parse DB instead? Is Parse a suitable Heroku replacement for serving cached files and scaling up as needed, etc.?

Do I maintain two databases (one at Parse and one on Heroku) and just create a Rake task that syncs the two?

What's the best way to approach this problem, so we keep the entire project as DRY as possible and also future-proof it so when we want to add more mobile clients and perhaps other clients in general, we can easily just add them on to the existing infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

I see many developers using Rails to deliver their API while taking advantage of Ember or Angular to build the front of the application. It makes it a lot easier to build the mobile app at the same time.